# Comparing two arrays in Python without loop

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

Suppose I have a array, i.e.

```
A=np.array[[4,7,8,9],[1,2,5],[],[6,7]]

V=np.array[6,3,1,9]
```

The answer I want is `B=np.array[[4],[1,2],[],[6,7]]`

I can do it using for loop, looping 4 times and comparing them one block by one block. I am wondering, is there any faster way of doing it? Maybe without for loop?

Comment: How do you get from A and V to B? Not clear to me from your example.

Comment: @perigon thank you for your replying, what I want is compare each element in array V with each block in array A i.e. [4,7,8,9]<=4 will return [true,false,false,false], hence the first block in B will be 4. etc.